# What are the options for watching Sgt. Frog / Keroro Gunso after episode 78, subtitled or dubbed, without resorting to unlicensed copies?

Tags: sgt-frog

Funimation has released DVDs for Sgt. Frog covering episodes 1-78.  Everything I have read on-line leads me to believe Funimation will not be releasing any more episodes.

If those of us in the USA want to watch episodes 79-358 of this show subtitled in English (or dubbed, although I find that unlikely) what options are available?  I have seen a few DVDs with confusing titles like "Keroro Gunso 4th Season 6", but when they specify the region, it is region 2, and I don't think that will work in my home entertainment PC.

I am not interested in any answers relating to unlicensed copies or derivative works.